# Why symmetric potential has even bound ground state and does odd ground state exist?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, potential, parity, ground-state

I have read that symmetric potential has even bound ground state, but I don't know how to derive it? The only conclusion I can derive is for even potential I can take real wavefunction.

I also want to ask, if odd bound ground state ever exist? I have never seen any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One particle wave function for a bound ground state does not have nodes. This is obviously not the case for the wave functions of several fermions, which necessarily have zeros to satisfy the Pauli principle. Note also that the wave functions of the eigenstates of a scalar potential can also always be chosen real.

Comment: If we do not have symmetric potential for one particle, then also we will have even wavefunction for ground state? or the wavefunction will be some uneven structure following node theorem?

Comment: The wave function does not have to be even, but for a ground state it will not have zeros. Node theorem does not say that the wave function should be symmetric.

Comment: Is this *exactly* correct?  It is known that  *if* the solution has no node it must be the ground state, and *if* solution $A$ has fewer nodes than solution $B$, then $E_A<E_B$, but it is clear that the ground state necessarily has no nodes?

Comment: Think for instance $V=(x^2-1)x e^{-x^2}$... it is clear the ground state has no nodes?

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Landau & Livehits base their argument on variational approach - the wave function with no nodes corresponding to the global minimum. I can't really add more. I don't understand your example - this is a potential?

Comment: The variational approach proves there’s always an even state, but it’s an approximate ground state.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero I am not sure we are talking the same language here: are you saying that the ground state is always even, i.e. $|\psi(-x)|^2 = |\psi(x)|^2$??

Comment: for symmetric potential I know "heuristically" that the ground state is even and has no nodes.  As far as all the examples I know, it is also true that the ground state of any potential has no nodes but the node theorem only establishes ordering: $E_A<E_B$ implies A has fewer nodes than B.  It does not guarantee the ground state has none.  Neither does a variational approach, which is only as good as the ansatz you use.  Granted, if you find a variational wavefunction, the true ground state will be lower but again the variational approach *depends* on assumptions of the form of the solution.

Comment: I'm not in any way challenging your conclusion... Just I don't remember seeing a formal proof that the ground state has necessarily $0$ nodes.  I don't debate it has the fewest, or that all the examples of I know have $0$ nodes.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero I am not arguing with you either. I have merely recited the Landau's book, but I have never really looked into this issue beyond of what I read there.